# How to set id for multiples identic element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm searching a way to set a same id for multiples child. I did this in XSL :

```html
<xsl:template match="ref">
  <fields>
    <field name="" value=""/>
  </fields>
</xsl:template>
```

I got it in XML

```html
<refs>
    <ref alias="">
        <fields>
            <field name="something" value="something" />
            <field name="something" value="something" />
         </fields>
    </refs>
    <ref>
         <fields>
              <field name="something" value="something"/>
              <field name="something" value="something"/>

         </fields>
</ref>
</refs>
```

and I want this finally

```html
<refs>
    <ref alias="">
        <fields>
            <field name="something" value="something" index="0"/>
            <field name="something" value="something" index="0"/>
         </fields>
         </refs>
          <ref>
         <fields>
              <field name="something" value="something" index="1"/>
              <field name="something" value="something" index="1"/>
         </fields>
    </ref>
</refs>
```

How can I proceed to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="index">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(..)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assigns each `field` the unique id of its parent `fields`. The exact format of the id is processor-dependent.

Comment: I forgot to specify I set up my <fields> and <field> into XSL processing, template match cannot be use then :s

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I made my XML like :  <xsl:template match="ref">
<fields>
  <field />
  <field/> </fields>
</xsl:template>

Comment: I am afraid this is not getting any clearer. Is the XML in your post the input to your XSL transformation? If not, please edit your question and post an example of the real input, as well as your existing stylesheet.

Comment: I've just a XML with <refs><ref> and into a XSL file I did <xsl:template match="ref"><fields><field></field></fields> </xsl:template>

Comment: If the `field` elements are hard-coded into your stylesheet, then why don't also you add the ids there?

Comment: Because I'll compile in Handlebars like : {{#each field}} <input name="something.{{index}}.{{name}}"/> {{/each}}

Comment: @alexis I am afraid I have no clue what you want. Please refer to the help section on how to ask, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I edit, now its ok?

Comment: i got it, i'm just retard I didn't understand I should create an other file to put in your code u gave me. Thanks and sorry for all